# Show products per shortcode

Tags: php, shortcode

I have been trying to display products on my homepage in a carousel/slider for some time.
I got downloaded an excellent plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/carousel-slider/ which does everything i have been looking for.

I tried in a test page, copying the shortcodes and it worked great.

I then copied the shortcodes into my custom homepage template as so:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[carousel_slide id='95064']' ); ?>
```

when I opened my website in the browser, i got an error appear

> Fatal error: syntax error, unexpected '95064' (T_LNUMBER), expecting ',' or ')' in /homepages/8/d692312546/htdocs/SupplementGenie/wp-content/themes/Supplement Genie/test-menu.php on line 160

I then changed the short code from `'95064'` to `"95064"`

so it was:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[carousel_slide id="95064"]' ); ?>
```

refreshed the page and the page loaded fine. the produts where there but rather than 1 row of 4 columns across the screen. All 12 products where showing in 1 column of 12 rows down the screen

As far as i can see the styling has been lost.

When I paste the short code directly into wordpress as

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[carousel_slide id='95064']' ); ?>
```

It works great, Inhave a feeling it may be something to do with swapping `'95064'` for `"95064"` but am unsure

Has anyone else had a similar problem? does anyone know how to sort this?

I have tried adding to functions.php:

```
add_filter('carousel_slider_load_scripts', 'carousel_slider_load_scripts');
function carousel_slider_load_scripts( $load_scripts ) {
return true;
}
```

To try and force the scripts to load but does not seem to be working

Comment: You have a syntax error, `<?php echo do_shortcode('[carousel_slide id="95064"]' ); ?>` is correct, you need to troubleshoot for row and columns.

Comment: @Akshat I have added the code above to functions.php but still no joy

Comment: If `'95064'` works and `"95064"` doesn't, then try with `<?php echo do_shortcode("[carousel_slide id='95064']" ); ?>`

Comment: @sally CJ. None of them work in my custom template. They site the products but the styling and accepts are missing. I need to find a way to force the scripts to load

Comment: 'When I paste the short code directly into wordpress as' - where did you paste it? Is it the visual/TinyMCE editor? One thing I can suggest (for now) is, create a widgetized area (that's shown *only* on the custom template) and add a widget there with the Shortcode (i.e. *just* `[carousel_slide id="95064"]`).

Comment: Also, you can try using the code with the standard templates such as `page.php` - put the (PHP) code there and see if it works. If yes, then you could re-create the custom template, maybe by copying `page.php`.